# md5sum fails to find file after changing dir in a Makefile instruction

Tags: makefile, md5sum

I am having trouble generating a package with a md5sum of the contained files using Makefiles.

I do have found an workaround, but I am not satisfied with it.

This is a example of how my makefile works, it can be used to reproduce my problem with `file1`, and my workaround with `file2`.

```
    VERSION:=1
    DIR:=tmp

    file: #rule to build the file with current version tag
            touch $(DIR)/file-$(VERSION)

    $(DIR)/file1.tar:file #rule that fails to create the md5 file
            cd $(DIR)
            md5sum -b \
                    file-$(VERSION) \
                    >> file-$(VERSION).md5
            tar -cf $@ \
                    file-$(VERSION) \
                    file-$(VERSION).md5
            cd -

    $(DIR)/file2.tar:file #workaround that fails to create the md5 file
            md5sum -b \
                    $(DIR)/file-$(VERSION) \
                    >> $(DIR)/file-$(VERSION).md5
            tar -cf $@ -C $(DIR) \
                    file-$(VERSION) \
                    file-$(VERSION).md5

    file1: $(DIR) $(DIR)/file1.tar

    file2: $(DIR) $(DIR)/file2.tar

    $(DIR):
            mkdir -p $(DIR)
```

Running `file1`, the build fails and I get the following output:

```
:~/tmp$ make file1
mkdir -p tmp
touch tmp/file-1
cd tmp
md5sum -b \
    file-1 \
    >> file-1.md5
md5sum: file-1: No such file or directory
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'tmp/file1.tar' failed
make: *** [tmp/file1.tar] Error 1
```

Running `file2`, the file is built successfully:

```
:~/tmp$ make file2
touch tmp/file-1
md5sum -b \
    tmp/file-1 \
    >> tmp/file-1.md5
tar -cf tmp/file2.tar -C tmp \
    file-1 \
    file-1.md5
```

My question is, why `md5sum` tool fails to find the file in the same dir as it is running after calling `cd dir` when it is used as a `Makefile` instruction? Or, what I am missing?

Comment: Each line in a recipe is executed by a separate shell invocation. So your `cd $(DIR)` line is executed by a shell and has no effect on the next line (`md5sum...`)  that gets executed by another shell.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, thanks man. I'm used to see `cd` and `cd -` always in the same line, but never thought it was a requirement. Just added `; \` at end of each instruction to be interpreted as a single line and it is working now. Could you answer the question so I can accept it?

Comment: Question answered. Note that, depending on what you'd like to happen when a command fails, you can also chain your commands with `&&` or `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in a recipe is executed by a separate shell invocation. So your `cd $(DIR)` line is executed by a shell and has no effect on the next line (`md5sum...`) that gets executed by another shell. In your case a simple solution consists in chaining all commands such that they are considered as a single line by make and executed by the same shell:

```
target: prerequisites
    cd here; \
    do that; \
    ...
```

or:

```
target: prerequisites
    cd here && \
    do that && \
    ...
```